# AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync returns : The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to use AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync to exchange code with token per below:

```
clientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ClientId"].ToString(), "12345");

string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket?.Identity.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

var authority = "https://abc.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/XXX-SIGNINSIGNUP/v2.0";
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, false, new WebSessionCache(userObjectID));

//Aquiring access_token by passing code
AuthenticationResult result = authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azure.B2C.RedirectUrl"].ToString()), credential).Result;
```

However I keep getting this error:

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

I had a quick look at Azure AD Library below:
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/2b53bb4e641da49e9f678f32e7f7c204290a72f2/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/Internal/Instance/Authenticator.cs#L105

Where it doesn't seem to support the new b2clogin domains i.e. it's not supporting version and policy:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin

[image]

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You findings are correct, ADAL does not support Azure AD B2C. More importantly it's deprecated. Please move to MSAL for full Azure AD B2C support. For guidance take a look at [Migrate applications to the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL).](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-migration)